# Simple recursion on Codeacademy

Tags: python, math, recursion

Currently doing a recursion tutorial on codecademy. It tells me that I'm right and can go onto the next lesson, but also comes up with:

```
File "python", line 6
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So obviously it isn't right! Can you have a look at the link and tell me whats up?!
I'm so confused!

http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-7f7dx/0/2#

If my code doesn't appear it is:

```
def timesTwo(n):
    if(n == 0):
        return '2 x 0 = 0'

    n*2
    else: 
        return timesTwo(n-1) + 2
```

Thanks guys

Comment: def timesTwo(n):
 if(n == 0):
  return 0
 
 else: 
     n*2
 return timesTwo(n-1) + 2

Comment: See my answer and let me know if it doesn't work for you.  Otherwise, accept the answer please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will work for you.

```
def timesTwo(n):
    if(n == 0):
        return 0 # What is 2 x 0 again? I forgot... 
    else: 
        return timesTwo(n-1) + 2  #You write this!
```

I'm also not sure why you're doing `n * 2` after a return.  That's a syntax error as your `if` is missing its `else`.

Comment: but don't you need to multiply n by 2? otherwise timesTwo(n) doesn't do anything right?

Comment: maybe I'm understanding it wrong. I'm confused because, say you inputed n = 2, you want the result to be 4 because 2 x 2 = 4. so then timesTwo(n-1) + 2 would equal 2 - 1 + 2 which is 3, and thats wrong?

Comment: @user3540853 `timesTwo(2) = timesTwo(2-1) + 2 = timesTwo(1-1)+2+2 = 0+2+2 = 4`

Comment: @NadirSampaoli thank you so much! I was so confused!

Comment: @NadirSampaoli just to make sure that I understand. we stop at timesTwo(1-1) because after that n==0?

Comment: Yes.  That will hit the `if(n == 0): return 0` case.

Comment: accepted the answer :) i've edited my question - just want to make sure i completely understand recursion! @tristan

Comment: maybe I should ask it as a separate question though..im new to stack overflow I'm afraid!

Comment: @user3540853 when your question significantly changes, please open a new question. this allows the question to be satisfied at some point.

Comment: don't be afraid -- stackoverflow is here for Q&A.  good on you for taking it as a learning exercise and not just moving along

Comment: thanks @tristan i'll post it as a new question :) thank you for all of your help, i just want to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error has to do with how Python interprets indentation at the beginning of lines. Because `n*2` is an expression lined up vertically with the `if` line, instead of being indented, it effectively signals the *end* of the `if` block. That means that, instead of `else` being associated with the `if`, it is dangling by itself—which is illegal.

By contrast, this code doesn't have a syntax error because there is only indented code between the `if` and the `else`:

```
# NOTE: this code still has problems!
def timesTwo(n):
    if(n == 0):
        return '2 x 0 = 0'
        n * 2
    else:
        return timesTwo(n-1) + 2
```

However, there are at least two other major errors with this code. One is that the expression `n * 2` is unreachable because it comes right after a `return` statement (make sure you grok this because it's important to understand what `return` does). Another has to do with what the `n == 0` case does, which will hopefully be clear if you try running `timesTwo(1)` and see what happens...